# How to change LinPhone SIP Port on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, port, sip, linphone

Does anybody know how change SIP port for Linphone-iPhone ( The iOS Version ) to something other than its default value ( 5060 ) ?

Comment: I am stuck in same issue. Can you please tell me if you have found the solution?

Comment: Yeah, I searched everywhere ( literally everywhere ) and there's no working instruction anywhere. I myself found the solution after weeks of trial and error, But it's a bit complicated, and it's not easy to describe it here. I prefer to talk somewhere else where I can tell you what to do step by step and you do it at the same time ;)

Comment: @Unkn0wn.Bit have you posted your solution somewhere? I am stuck in the same issue.

Comment: No, But I have sent my self-found self-tested solution to many guys who were trying to do this ... If you need that, contact me via email at amir.sepehrom@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

Below links may be help you:-

1)[http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group_*linphone*_address.html#gaae9f86270cefa9614026a743d4dd29f3](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__linphone__address.html#gaae9f86270cefa9614026a743d4dd29f3)

2)https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-developers/2014-01/msg00033.html

Comment: Your first link refers to the method I mentioned above. It doesn't work.
And your second link refers to the question "I" emailed to the linphone developers mailing list, but nobody answered "me" :D

Comment: Ya.. I know about second link.. I have posted because I cant understand your question as much... So I thought that link may be help you. :)

Comment: Yeah, That second link is written and posted by me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you choose SIP Account while login, and tapped **TLS**, it automatically goes to **5061**, I suspected!

But if you want port something different than 5060 and 5061 you can change it using **Settings** screen by tapping on account name and adding **proxy**.

Like this:
[image]

After editing proxy and tapping back button, it will automatically starts connecting to given port(thanks for logs)

---

BTW, I wanted to put comment on @mixtly87, but don't know how to add image in comment :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but maybe this can be helpful:

```
    LCSipTransports transport;
    linphone_core_get_sip_transports(linphoneCore, &transport);
    transport.tls_port = 5061;
    linphone_core_set_sip_transports(linphoneCore, &transport);
```

This code can be placed in `createCore` method, where linphoneCore is created.